# What does "put a squeeze on them" mean in this case?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

I was listening to one of my favourite songs, but since English is not my mother tongue, usually I do not understand all the words, mostly because I listen to hip hop.

I searched for the meaning of "put a squeeze on them", but I am still not sure what it means in the following music:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GPrXkyJrTc

Be careful: it is real hip hop!

Comment: [1/2] A few notes:. First: it is common courtesy for you, the questioner, to include the relevant context or quote in which the word you're interested appears. It's somewhat rude to make the people you're asking for help go watch a 5-minute video and guess which lyric you're asking about. Second: musical lyrics are like poems, and musicians can take the same liberties with language as poets can (the famed *poetic license*), and force words to mean whatever they need to mean in order to meet the demands of meter and rhyme. For that reason, interpretation of lyrics is off-topic here.

Comment: [2/2] For more on what's considered on- and off-topic here, see the two lists in the [help/on-topic]. Finally, just so you're not left empty-handed here, "*put the squeeze on*" is old gangster (as in *Al Capone gangster*, decades prior to *Gang Starr gangster*) slang for "***extort*** *money from*". You're going to *squeeze* the victim until money drops out.

Comment: @DanBron Don't come to me with a prayer, if you don't want to listen to the music, just don't look at the question anymore, no? Instead of saying it is of topic or not, I know how stackexchange works, and I don't give quite a damn sincerely. I give help when and if I can and when I need help I ask help. Simple as that. All the rest is just waste of time, many times. If you cannot listen to 5 minutes music, then this question is not for you.

Comment: No, that is not how this works. The question is not *not for me*, it is *not for this site*. You are error; you have violated the rules of both topicality and common courtesy. "Quiet sincerely not giving a damn" about what's on- and -off topic is a rude, counterproductive, and dangerous attitude to adopt here.

Comment: @DanBron Ok, you are right dude. Have a nice day! By the way, I will try to be more specific next time. Thanks for the prayer :)

Comment: @DanBron A little question: if 'lyrics' are off topic, why do we have that as a tag? To the original poster, 'added' a tag and +1 *because* as non-native speakers, we don't understand many words/phrases in lyrics that *natives* find it quite easy to understand. Lyrics **are** on-topic because they are **in** English. **And** if there's poetic license or register, it means linguists **do** take care of such style! :) No offense whatsoever.

Comment: A little suggestion: Next time, when you have a video/audio of longer length, to save others' time, simply mention the exact time in video. The answerers may play around it and get you the answer. For them, it'll be time saving and easier.

Comment: Hey, I just came across this. Typical way to ask about videos/audios. Check here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57402/question-about-some-sentences-of-this-snl-video

Comment: @MaulikV Thank you! I'll try to be more concrete next time ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's easy to find the meaning of the idiomatic usage by Googling [**define "put the squeeze on"**](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=YyRfVf6PM8XI8gfQiYCYBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=define+%22put+the+squeeze+on%22). Google helpfully displays its own definition **(informal) coerce or pressurize (someone)**, so you don't even need to follow any links to actual dictionaries.

Comment: Questions about song lyrics are not universally off-topic even though such questions tend to be more likely to fall outside the bounds. The source of a question doesn't make it off-topic as we've discussed a lot on meta. This particular question is off-topic as it's written because it's answerable with a simple search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [**put *the* squeeze on**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+the+squeeze+on) and it is an idiomatic expression which largely refers to "trying to use influence to make a person/organisation act in the way you want" or "pressure to obtain money". "Put the heat on" is also a similar idiom. If you think of the words "squeeze" or "heat" in an abstract way, you get the feeling of "pressure" and that's what these two expressions boil down to. "Put pressure on someone/something".

> I watched y'all get fat, now I want my share.
>
> What you ain't got it all? Then I want what's there.
>
> The most influential men, got influential friends
>
> And I'm a put the squeeze on all of 'em.

Here we can see it in context. Guru (the emcee) is aiming to put pressure on the people who hold influence in order to claim his share (of influence/power/money).

Good Hip Hop = Insightful learning - careful though; it's hard to understand!